# Kafka Streams - How to better control partitioning of internally created state store topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, partitioning, apache-kafka-streams

State stores in Kafka Streams are created internally. 
State stores are partitioned by key, but do not allow to provide partitioning other than *by key* (to my knowledge).

**QUESTIONS**

How to **control the number of partitions of a state-store internally created topic**? How does the state store topic infer the number of partitions and the partitioning to use by default, and how to override?

How to work it around if you want to partition your state-store by something other than the key of your incoming key-value record and have co-partitioning? In this case, I'd like to partition by something more specific than my regular key. E.g. I have a

```
case class RegularKey(fieldA: String)
```

and I want to partition by

```
case class SpecificKey(fieldA: String, fieldB: String)
```

For my incoming source topic, I am using a HashPartitioner on the number of partitions.

Answer (score 2):

The number of changelog topic partitions depends in the number of input topic partitions and you cannot change it, because the state is shared based on this number (ie, there is one partitions by shard).

If you want to partition changelog topic by some attribute, you must set it as key. In your case, you must set `SpecificKey` as message key. It's not allowed to change the partitioning because it would "break" Kafka Streams leading to incorrect result.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused here:

"If you want to partition by some attribute, you must set it as key." > You mean, set it as key - of the StateStore, or in both?

"In your case, you must set SpecificKey as message key." > "Message Key" or "State Store record key"? 

So, if I use RegularKey in my input topic, and SpecificKey in my state store, would the State Store changelog still be partitioned by RegularKey? Would that be fault-tolerant? Or I **must** use the same key in the input topic and in the state store?

Comment: You must have the same key. However, you can set a new key, and pipe the data through intermediate repartition topic to get what you want. If you use DSL, the repartioning will happen automatically under the hood. If you use Processor API, you need to do it manually.

Comment: OK, same key in store and topic. However, I think it would be nice to be able to provide StateStorePartitioner to provide same key as input topic to have different keys. Partitionkey and datakey need not be equal on the StateStore, although StateStore partitionkey needs to be equal to the input topic partitionkey.

If I use SpecificKey as StateStore record key (which I'm doing), I suppose that the underlying changelog topic will 1) have the same number of partitions of input topic and 2) using HashPartitioner would send SpecificKey keys to any partition causing non-collocation. Is that it?

Comment: Re-reading this, I think I may have failed to explain myself. Conversation is focused on "repartition" of the StateStore topic, which is not desired. What I would actually want to do is to use the same partitioning as original topic, i.e. "not-to-repartition" the StateStore topic, but still be able to use "SpecificKey" instead of "RegularKey" as key in the StateStore. Which is supported by API but if I understand correctly, it would repartition data differently "breaking" my app. Is this correct?

Comment: If you don't shard the state based on the same key as the input topics, you loose data locality/co-partitioning and thus your application will compute incorrect results.

Comment: @matthias-j-sax I just mean that the state store partitioning must be the same as original topic, no doubts there, but that it would be good that your store key could be different (keeping partitioning). Just in case, my solution:  keep a store where K: original input topic key , V: Map[fieldB-type, Value-To-Store]. It is not natural though.
It would be good to point out somewhere that API allows something (using a different key in your store than the key in your original topic) that would break your computation... it looks to me that using a different record key in store should be possible.

Comment: In fact, Kafka doesn't rehash your keys to log your new record to changelog topic. It reuses partition number from the whole task. Thus, if you read from some topic with partition X and use transformer or processor to put (and, consequently get) your records to/from store, it will put this record to the initial partition of your task. And expects to find it during read operations in the same partition - partition of your task.