# How to implement GDPR right-to-forget (delete) in Kafka Streams with stores and Processor API?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, partitioning, apache-kafka-streams

This question is about implementing GDPR in a Kafka Streams application, with a full retention topic with stateful processing using Processor API.

Say an application receives events. There are different clients, and clients have users, and these users produce events to the "events" topic.

For allowing "right to forget", you have to be able to delete data on demand for a (clientId, userId) pair, and not just delete based on retention. You can have this by the "compact" policy.

If I keep (as I was doing in a non-compacted topic) the key as (clientId, userId), the compaction will reduce all (clientId, userId) records to one, clearly not what I want.

I understand that I can have a Record Key like this: (clientId, userId, eventId) and a Partitioner that uses (clientId, userId) % numPartitions, and in order to delete records from a user I can do it by reading from beginning, filtering those records with (clientId, userId), which will be in the same partition, and go adding a ( (clientId, userId, eventId) -> null )  record there.

But, doing it this way, I need the state stores associated to keep the same partitioning as the source topic, i.e. (clientId, userId), but not the same key. Would this be feasible?

How to delete from state store topics? Reacting to the "null" value in your Processor code is quite cumbersome (since you have data by (clientId, userId), not (clientId, userId, eventId)).

---

Reference on general [GDPR on Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/handling-gdpr-log-forget/) and please do not include encryption-based solutions like [Daniel Lebrero's](http://danlebrero.com/2018/04/11/kafka-gdpr-event-sourcing/) - insightful, though.

Answer (score 1):

> But, doing it this way, I need the state stores associated to keep the same partitioning as the source topic, i.e. (clientId, userId), but not the same key. Would this be feasible?

Yes. If the input topic are partitions by (clientId, userId) the stores will be partitioned the same way. If you repartition data in your app, you can pass a custom `StreamPartitioner` to preserve the (clientId, userId) partitioning scheme.

> How to delete from state store topics? Reacting to the "null" value in your Processor code is quite cumbersome (since you have data by (clientId, userId), not (clientId, userId, eventId)).

Not sure why this would be cumbersome? Even if the input topic is partitioned by (clientId, userId), the key is still (clientId, userId, eventId) and the full key is used in the store.

Comment: "Even if the input topic is partitioned by (clientId, userId), the key is still (clientId, userId, eventId) and the full key is used in the store." >> I understood from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004841/kafka-streams-how-to-better-control-partitioning-of-internally-created-state-s) that keys in state stores rule their partitioning, so I understood that in state stores my record key in the state store must be the same as the partitioning, in this case, (client, user), and that if it is (client, user, event) it would break partitioning.

Comment: The other question is the general case for which you use the whole key to partition the data. Thus, the answer there is not completely exact: stores are partitioned based on the corresponding input-topic partitioning schema. Because by default, the topic partitioning schema is key-based, the other answer is not "wrong" per-se -- just not precise.

Comment: I'll try to make it simpler.
I don't want to use the full key (clientId, userId, evenId) as key of the store. I want (clientId, userId) as key of the store (otherwise events won't get associated), which is the same *partitioning* of the input topic, but which is different to the *record key* of the input topic. Would that be OK?

Comment: I don't think you can use (clientId, userId) in the store, because---from my understanding---the store needs to hold multiple events with same (clientId, userId) at the same time. Thus, similar to preventing log-compaction to delete records with same (clientId, userdId) you need to add eventId into the store, too. Partitioning will still be fine because the local store does not know anything about partitioning in the first place and will just accept the data.

Comment: And for the underlying changelog topic, we don't use key-based partitioning but "pin" the changelog partitions to the input topic partitions (ie, on write, we explicitly specify the partition number as the same of input topic partition---key-based hashing is not used when writing to changelog topics).

Comment: These comments clarify a lot - I couldn't find this in the docs, I suggest this is clarified there. For the store: I have different usages. In one I keep the "last channel value" for a (clientId, userId). Another one keeps "last session by channel", so a (clientId,user) can have parallel open sessions. But another one is windowed which keeps sessions "yet unassociated to an order" for a certain (clientId, userId), so when an order comes, I can associate these sessions to that order.  If I use 3-way key, how could I "group-by" (client,user) and query efficiently?

Comment: You could o range queries with (client,user) as prefix. But you need to understand the byte[] layout in RocksDB. Even than, rabge queries would not be as efficient than single key lookups...